# Drivers for Dell Precision M90 and Windows Server 2008 (R1)

Tags: windows-server-2008, drivers, video

I am trying to get multi monitor support for a laptop. I have installed Windows Server 2008 (R1) x64 and none of the dell drivers for the laptop seem to work (I have tried the x64 ones for Vista and XP, they don't offer Win7 ones yet).

Drivers downloaded from NVidia do not work (NVidia says I need to get Drivers from Dell).

Do I have any alternatives?

The Video card is an NVidia Quadro FX 4800m (I tried the NVidia Quandro FX 4800 driver and it would not install).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check here:  http://forums.laptopvideo2go.com/

You'll want to look for a series that supports your card (it'll be listed in the individual thread).  Look for x64 Vista ones or Windows 7 ones.

It appears that this one will work and it's the latest:  http://forums.laptopvideo2go.com/topic/25193-v19100-windows-7vista-64bit-nvidia/

But again, it's trial and error on them.  Some people like older driver sets if the performance is better...so you'll need to look around on there and download a few and find the one that works best for you.

Comment: @Vaccano - Very welcome